# Perl module broke my windows xampp installation

Tags: perl, apache, windows-7, xampp, cpan

PROBLEM: In the process of trying to install gitstat on a Windows7 machine I broke my xampp Apache installation.  Now I can't get gitstat or apache to work.

APACHE ERROR:

```
[error] Can't load Perl file: C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/startup.pl for server localhost:80, exiting...`
```

Other people have reported this issue being caused by the PERL5LIB environment variable, but that variable does not exist on my machine.

WHAT I DID / GITSTAT ERROR:

I needed the SOAP::Lite module installed so I followed the windows guide here: http://soaplite.com/install.html

As far as I could tell I installed the module successfully, console output below

```
cpan[1]> install SOAP::Lite
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.21)
Going to read '\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 27 Jun 2012 02:47:03 GMT
SOAP::Lite is up to date (0.714).
```

I saw a SOAP directory in perl/site/lib which (to me) means that the module should be available.  When I look in my perllocal.pod file SOAP:Lite is in there.

Part of the gitstat installation instructions say to copy the Lite.pm file from perl/site/lib/SOAP into gitstat\gstat_pl\lib

However, when I try to perform step nine of gitstat installation (perl gitstat.pl HEAD) I get the following:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\gitstat\gstat_pl>perl gitstat.pl HEAD
 Supported versions:

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm line 34
86.
Compilation failed in require at C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/SOAP/Constants.pm line 1
3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/SOAP/Constants.pm li
ne 13.
Compilation failed in require at lib/Lite.pm line 3444.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Lite.pm line 3444.
Compilation failed in require at gitstat.pl line 30.
```

If I don't copy the file from perl/site/lib/SOAP then I get

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\gitstat\gstat_pl>perl gitstat.pl HEAD
Can't locate lib/Lite.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl
/site/lib .) at gitstat.pl line 30.
```

I don't understand why CPAN didn't install the Lite.pm module in the @INC path or why the compilation might fail when the module is available, or most importantly why my Apache install is broken.  Also I'm very new to Perl and CPAN and my understanding of Apache is primitive so simpler explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you still get the Apache error if you remove Lite.pm from your gitstat directory?

Comment: The [INSTALL](http://gitstat.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gitstat/gitstat/INSTALL) file makes no mention of SOAP::Lite.

Comment: Stevenl: Yes I get the error whether or not any Lite.pm file is in gitstat.

Comment: Daxim: Thanks, you are totally right.  I needed Mime::Lite  after installing that module I discovered that I get another error:
List form of pipe open not implemented at Makefile.PL

I'm not too concerned about getting gitstat installed on this windows machine, but I really need to get apache working again.  I deleted my old perl installation and installed strawberry perl in xampp, still nothing, same error.  Any more ideas?

Comment: You need to tell XAMPP to employ Strawberry Perl, it still points at the location of its now deinstalled bundled Perl.

Comment: How can I do that? I opened httpd-perl.conf in apache\conf\extra On the first line I see LoadFile "C:/xampp/perl/bin/perl510.dll" I know this is wrong because the dll in Strawberry is perl514.dll but if I change file to say that Apache still wont start... How would you tell XAMPP to employ Strawberry Perl?